# Is this Jasmine test correctly testing my http request? Cannot seem to make it fail

Tags: angular, jasmine, automated-tests

Have a simple service in my HttpService class that just makes a http request to a url that is passed in. I am trying to test that this service is working properly. I wrote a test in Jasmine that makes a call to my dashbaord API and expects the connection request to be the exact url the app should be on. The test passes but I cannot seem to make the test fail, this has me believe I am not properly testing my getData service.

Here is my test class

```
  describe('httpService', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpModule],
    providers: [
      HttpService,

      { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
    ]
  });
});

afterEach(inject([XHRBackend], (mockBackend) => mockBackend.verifyNoPendingRequests()));

describe('getData', () => {

  it('should call dashbaord API', inject([HttpService, XHRBackend], (service: HttpService, mockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        expect(connection.request.url).toBe('http://localhost:4200/dashboard');
    });
```

The Service that does my http request is structure like this:

```
getRequest(url: string): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get(url).....
```

I believe I am on the right track. Any input would be great.

Update: Okay so I rewrote the entire test and I think it is actually working. Any input on this new code below would be great :)

```
    describe('httpService', () => {
    let service: HttpService;
    let httpClient: HttpTestingController;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [HttpService]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(HttpService);
        httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)
    });

 it('should pass', () => {
     service.getData('http://localhost:4200/dashboard').subscribe(result => {
         expect(result).toBe(true);
     });
     httpClient.expectOne("http://localhost:4200/dashboard").event(
        new HttpResponse<boolean>({ body: true }));
 })


});
```